# Memory management for panorama tour

Tags: memory, aframe, panoramas

Building a tour of iPhone partial panoramas.
There are some 40+ of them and it seems as if memory is running out on mobile devices.

Also, using version A-frame 0.5.0, the code below works on desktop, but not in latest version 0.9.2.

```
<a-entity id="pano_01" visible="true">
<a-curvedimage asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/Upgrade.jpg" height="145" radius="100" theta-length="300" rotation="0 33 0"></a-curvedimage>
<a-sky asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/Upgrade_sky.jpg" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-sky>
<a-image asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/UI_Next.png" position="0 -0.5 -3" scale="0.35 0.35 0.35" onclick="setpano_02()"></a-image>
</a-entity>

<a-entity id="pano_02" visible="false">
<a-sky asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/JRO_Arrive_sky.jpg"></a-sky>
<a-curvedimage asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/JRO_Arrive.jpg" height="140" radius="100.0" theta-length="300" rotation="0 60 0"></a-curvedimage>
<a-image asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/UI_Next.png" position="1 -0.5 -3" scale="0.35 0.35 0.35" onclick="setpano_03()"></a-image>
<a-image asset-on-demand="src: ../Html_Templates/pix/UI_Back.png" position="-1 -0.5 -3" scale="0.35 0.35 0.35" onclick="setpano_01()"></a-image>
</a-entity>
```

Java that support the above:

```
function setpano_01() {
 document.getElementById('pano_01').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
 document.getElementById('pano_02').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
}
function setpano_02() {
 document.getElementById('pano_01').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
 document.getElementById('pano_02').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
 document.getElementById('pano_03').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
```

My expectation is that the asset-on-demand script would help in releasing memory resources, but it seems it does not work for this strategy.
Also, I was hoping the latest version of A-Frame would have improved memory management.

(I hope the question is now better phrased).

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. As is, your question may be too broad. Also, "does not work" is not a useful problem description. Please add your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom component called aframe-asset on demand.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-asset-on-demand-component

It dymanically loads images as assets and also removes them from memory.
This will probably solve your graphic memory problems.

"Remove Asset from Memory when not needed anymore. If you just remove the Texture from an entity, it will not be removed from entirely from THREE.JS and still use precious memory (precious especially on mobile). The A-Frame Asset OnDemand makes sure, that the Asset is removed in a way that free's up memory."

I found this by googling 'aframe dynamically load assets'

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am actually using the asset-on-demand component.
As far as fetching the asset it works, but it does to seem to be doing the clearing part so efficiently.
Since I use a strategy of switching the visibilty of entities sections, I'm suspecting it might not fit the scheme of the component.

Comment: Also, funny thing is, the code works fine under version 0.5.0.
But not under newer versions.
I would very much like to get help to make it up to date with the current release 0.9.2.

Comment: I suggest simplifying the project down to a single load image and delete, and monitor the vram to see if you are in fact clearing memory on deletion. I don't see how changing visibility of entities would affect the deletion of an asset, but perhaps something is preventing the graphics card from releasing memory. When you get the simple addition and deletion of images working, slowly add in other functionality, and note when failure starts to occur.